# how to get access token for an app, whose user is using facebook mobile app?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I just want to get access token for my app from those users who use facebook from mobile(not iOS or Android), is it possible? HELP SOON, I got no results from google, I'm wiling to get me in right way before 1 May, thanks

Comment: Yes, this is possible.  You can do it with simple HTTP requests to the graph api.  Can you be more specific on how you are implementing your application?  What technologies you are using and what you have tried so far?

Comment: Thanks, I'm using PHP with JAVASCRIPT, and I'm using both in a way so that non JS users will be able to get the same UI in their browser, I was just wondering if someone isn't logged in on fb via web brower in mobile, but on FB mobile app, what'll be the solution of that, but you're right, I got it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use the PHP SDK on your server to retrieve data via the Graph API.  After you [download the SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk), all you have to do is initialize it and you will be able to make calls to the Graph API and then pass the data to your users (even if they do not have JavaScript enabled).

Here is how you initialize the PHP SDK (taken from the [Facebook Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) -

```
require_once("facebook.php");

$config = array();
$config[‘appId’] = 'YOUR_APP_ID';
$config[‘secret’] = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET';

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
```

Now that you have the `$facebook` object you can authorize the user with API calls like these :

- Facebook::getUser()
- Facebook::getLoginUrl()
- Facebook::getLogoutUrl()

You'll want to start by reading up about the `getLoginUrl()` [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/).